# Weld CDI in Java SE: PreDestroy annotated method called too early?

Tags: java, cdi, weld-se

given the following code, I wonder why the CacheManager is still "alive" after the call to the @PreDestroy annotated method (CacheManager#doCleanup) (see output at the end of this post).
Isn't Weld aware of the fact that it's still referenced ? And how to get this method called when the object is really not used anymore ?

**Main class**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] parameters) {
        //Init weld container        
        Weld weld = new Weld();
        WeldContainer container = weld.initialize();
        container.select(MyLauncher.class).get().startScanner();
        weld.shutdown();
    } 
}
```

**MyLaucher class**

```
@Singleton
public class MyLauncher {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
    @Inject
    private PeriodicScanner periodicScanner;

    public Future startScanner() {
        logger.info("Starting file producers...");
        return periodicScanner.doScan();
    }
}
```

**PeriodicScanner class...**

```
@Singleton
public class PeriodicScanner {

    @Inject
    private Logger logger;
    @Inject
    private CacheManager myCacheMgr;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactoryBuilder()
            .setNameFormat("periodic-%d")
            .build());

    public Future doScan() {
        return scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            myCacheMgr.doStuff();
            logger.info("Hello from PeriodicScanner");
        }, 1, 15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

}
```

And the **CacheManager class**:

```
@Singleton
public class CacheManager {
    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @PostConstruct
    private void doInit(){
        logger.info("PostConstruct called for ID {}", this.hashCode());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    private void doCleanup(){
        logger.info("Cleaning up for ID {}", this.hashCode());
    }

    public int doStuff(){
        logger.info("Doing stuff from instance ID {}", this.hashCode());
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Sep 06, 2017 3:47:51 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup <clinit>
INFO: WELD-000900: 2.4.4 (Final)
Sep 06, 2017 3:47:51 PM org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup startContainer
INFO: WELD-000101: Transactional services not available. Injection of @Inject UserTransaction not available. Transactional observers will be invoked synchronously.
Sep 06, 2017 3:47:52 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer fireContainerInitializedEvent
INFO: WELD-ENV-002003: Weld SE container 2d18aac9-f66d-4373-b581-9c5cababd65a initialized
[main] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.CacheManager - PostConstruct called for ID 611572016
[main] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.MyLauncher - Starting file producers...
[main] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.CacheManager - Cleaning up for ID 611572016
Sep 06, 2017 3:47:52 PM org.jboss.weld.environment.se.WeldContainer shutdown
INFO: WELD-ENV-002001: Weld SE container 2d18aac9-f66d-4373-b581-9c5cababd65a shut down
[periodic-0] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.CacheManager - Doing stuff from instance ID 611572016
[periodic-0] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.PeriodicScanner - Hello from PeriodicScanner
[periodic-0] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.CacheManager - Doing stuff from instance ID 611572016
[periodic-0] INFO com.mycompany.cdiplayground.PeriodicScanner - Hello from PeriodicScanner
```

As you can see, the **periodic scanner is still alive after the container shutdown**. For the moment, the only way for me to prevent *doCleanup()* to be called too early is to call get() on the Future object returned by *startScanner()*:

```
container.select(MyLauncher.class).get().startScanner().get();
```

This way, the main application thread won't exit.

Does anybody know a better way to do that?

Thanks

I

Comment: I think this bevaiour is reasonable. CDI knows nothing about the *thread* that is calling its beans. And the "destruction" of beans by CDI does not mean garbage collecting them, just that CDI has called their `@PreDestroy` hooks and forgotten about them. Try shutting down the `ScheduledExecutorService` in a `@PreDestroy` hook in `PeriodicScanner`, if you want to stop the `PeriodicScanner` after CDI is shut down.

Answer (score 1):

**The output is expected** - Weld cannot know about other threads you spin up and the main thread simply keeps going until it reaches `container.shutdown()`.

This method (surprisingly) terminates container which means calling the `@PreDestroy` methods and then letting go of references for those beans. But the other thread still keeps using these instances.

What you could do is:

- Move `container.shutdown()` out of main method

  - Weld container would continue to work after `main()` method exits
  - You should place `container.shutdown()` to a method which will be called after the executor is done (depends on your code)
- Do NOT call `container.shutdown()` at all

  - Weld itself registers a [shutdown hook](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/latest/en-US/html_single/#_cdi_se_module) which triggers upon JVM termination
  - The viability of this solution depends on how you terminate your program
  - You can also implement your own shutdown hook and register that one instead

As a side note - if you are only looking for a way to create a "wait" in your main thread just to let another thread do the job, you might be better off just putting that logic into main thread.